# Sleep until a specific time/date - AIX

Tags: aix

```
echo $(($(date -d 'tomorrow 00:00:00' +%s) - $(date +%s)))
```

What will be the syntax for AIX?

Answer (score 0):

The standard date command on AIX is very limited compared to the GNU date command.

You'll need to use Perl or something else to get a specific date on AIX. Or you could install GNU date from IBM's Linux Application toolbox:

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/download.html

Another option would be to simply use the Cron scheduler to run you process at a specific time.